# Creating a method with a for loop to find odd abundant sigma function numbers

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to create a method that will take a number and determine whether the number is an odd, abundant number with the sigma function. An abundant number is any number that when put into the sigma function generates a sum greater than the number given.

For instance, sigma(12) is abundant because sigma(12) = 1+2+3+4+6+12 = 28. However, it is not odd, so my method would not consider it. I can't figure out why my loop function isn't working , because when I try to input a range it spits up a bunch of number gibberish. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;


public class OddAbundant {
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void findOddAbundant(){
    System.out.println("Please enter the start of the range you want to test for odd abundant integers");
    int startRange = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the end of the range you want to test for odd abundant integers");
    int endRange = input.nextInt();
    for(int b = startRange; b <= endRange; b++) {
        if (Sigma.Sigma(b)<(b*2))   
            continue;
        else{
            if (b % 2 == 1)
                System.out.println(b);
        }


    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    findOddAbundant();


    }

}
```

I go through the loop and I can't figure out what's going wrong. I've tested the sigma method, which I can provide if it will help you guys, and it does spit out the correct value when given an integer. Thoughts?

Here is my sigma function:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sigma {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int Sigma(int s){
    int a = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=s;i++){
        if(s%i==0)
            a = a + i;

    }
    System.out.print(a);
    return a;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the number you want to perform the sigma function on");
    int s = input.nextInt();
    Sigma.Sigma(s);
    System.out.print(" is the sum of all the divisors of your input" ); 
    }

}
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: @nommyravian - my output is a string of numbers that grow extremely large, way past what I input for my endrange. I get this when I enter the range 1 - 50:                                                       Please enter the start of the range you want to test for odd abundant integers
1
Please enter the end of the range you want to test for odd abundant integers
50
1343
765
1287
15139
181211
281413
242415
311817
392019
423221
362423
603125
424027
563029
723231
634833
544835
913837
605639
904241
964443
847845
724847
1245749
93

Comment: can you quickly tell me what output are you expecting? take a smaller range for instance.

Comment: @nommyravian I want the output to be all the odd, abundant numbers that are produced by the sigma function within the range given. I was wrong in my original post and I edited it now, however. So for instance, sigma(12) = 1+2+3+4+6+12 = 28 which is greater than 2*12, so it is considered an abundant number. 12 is not odd, however, so I don't want my method to show it. I looked it up and the first odd abundant number is 965, so if I give my method a range from 1 - 966, the only number that should show is 965. Does that make sense?

Comment: post your sigma function in the question as well.

Comment: See my answer and accept it if it's working for you. For me, it's giving the answer 945 for the range 1-966.

Comment: Your definition of sigma is broken. For sigma of `n`, you want all divisors strictly less than (**not** less than or equal to) `n`. That is, `sigma(12) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16`. According to *your* definition, all numbers (including primes) are abundant, as at a minimum all numbers are divisible by themselves and one, and `n + 1 > n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The silly problem it was; remove the print statement from Sigma function.

```
public static int Sigma(int s){
    int a = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=s;i++){
        if(s%i==0)
            a = a + i;

    }
    System.out.print(a); //why do you have it here?
    return a;

}
```

Comment: I had the print statement there because I wanted the sigma class to run on it's own (not just be called by different classes). I wanted it to print the answer, so I just moved the command to the main method in the sigma class and it worked fine. I'm still very new to programming in general and I make silly mistakes that this all the time. Quite frustrating. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: you're welcome but do consider Mac's comment under your question about Sigma's definition. He has got something to say.